# The metric and special conformal transformations

Tags: coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

In Conformal Field Theory(Di Francesco et al.) chapter 4, the eq(4.17)
$$\dfrac{x^{'\mu}}{x^{'2}}=\dfrac{x^{\mu}}{x^2}-b^{\mu}.\tag{4.17}$$
can be derived from the last equation of (4.15)
$$x^{'\mu}=\dfrac{x^{\mu}-b^{\mu}x^2}{1-2b\cdot x+b^2x^2}.\tag{4.15}$$
Here I can't understand the calculation of $x^{'2}$. If I just simply use the original metric $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ to contract the $x^{'\mu}$ and $x^{'\nu}$, I can get the correct results. But If the $x^{'\mu}$ and $x^{'\nu}$ contract by $g_{\mu\nu}'(x')$ which is defined by eq(4.1) $$g_{\mu\nu}'(x')=\Lambda(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x),\tag{4.1}$$ the results will have an unexpected factor. The later contraction looks very reasonable, did I misunderstand something?

Comment: "reasonable"? Why is it reasonable to use *different* metrics on the left and right hand sides of the vectors (4.17) and (4.15)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here I use $x'^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}'(x')x^{'\mu}x^{'\nu}=\Lambda(x)g_{\mu\nu}x^{' \mu}x^{' \nu}$, and I think the new two vectors $x^{'\mu}$ should contract by the new metric. But it seems wrong, I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. This *is* the point. take a metric and stick to it.

Comment: Sorry,  I still can't understand why using the old metric to contract the new vectors. I think the point is the definition of $x^{'2}$. Is it related to active and passive transformation?

Comment: You are defining a vector and studying his properties. Your interpreting it as a new coordinate is subjective. You cannot use different traces on either side of an equation!

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know where I'm wrong. It should be understood as a new vector, not the change about the metric.